# How to configure a Two-legged Spring-OAuth provider/client?

Tags: java, spring, oauth

Im working on oauth 1 [Sparklr and Tonr](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/samples/oauth) sample apps and I'm trying to create a two-legged call. Hipoteticly the only thing you're supposed to do is change the Consumer Details Service from (Im ommiting the igoogle consumer info to simplify):

```
<oauth:consumer-details-service id="consumerDetails">
    <oauth:consumer name="Tonr.com" key="tonr-consumer-key" secret="SHHHHH!!!!!!!!!!" 
                resourceName="Your Photos"  resourceDescription="Your photos that you have uploaded to sparklr.com."/>
</oauth:consumer-details-service>
```

to:

```
<oauth:consumer-details-service id="consumerDetails">
    <oauth:consumer name="Tonr.com" key="tonr-consumer-key" secret="SHHHHH!!!!!!!!!!" 
                resourceName="Your Photos"  resourceDescription="Your photos that you have uploaded to sparklr.com." 
                requiredToObtainAuthenticatedToken="false" authorities="ROLE_CONSUMER"/>   
</oauth:consumer-details-service>
```

That's adding **requiredToObtainAuthenticatedToken** and **authorities** which will cause the consumer to be trusted and therefore all the validation process is skipped.

However I still get the login and confirmation screen from the Sparklr app. The current state of the official documentation is pretty precarious considering that the project is being absorbed by Spring so its filled up with broken links and ambiguous instructions. As far as I've understood, no changes are required on the client code so I'm basically running out of ideas. I have found people actually claiming that Spring-Oauth clients doesn't support 2-legged access (which I found hard to believe)

The only way I have found to do it was by creating my own ConsumerSupport:

```
private OAuthConsumerSupport createConsumerSupport() {
    CoreOAuthConsumerSupport consumerSupport = new CoreOAuthConsumerSupport();
    consumerSupport.setStreamHandlerFactory(new DefaultOAuthURLStreamHandlerFactory());
    consumerSupport.setProtectedResourceDetailsService(new ProtectedResourceDetailsService() {
                public ProtectedResourceDetails loadProtectedResourceDetailsById(
                        String id) throws IllegalArgumentException {
                    SignatureSecret secret = new SharedConsumerSecret(
                            CONSUMER_SECRET);

                    BaseProtectedResourceDetails result = new BaseProtectedResourceDetails();
                    result.setConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
                    result.setSharedSecret(secret);
                    result.setSignatureMethod(SIGNATURE_METHOD);
                    result.setUse10a(true);

                    result.setRequestTokenURL(SERVER_URL_OAUTH_REQUEST);
                    result.setAccessTokenURL(SERVER_URL_OAUTH_ACCESS);
                    return result;
                }
            });
    return consumerSupport;
}
```

and then reading the protected resource:

```
consumerSupport.readProtectedResource(url, accessToken, "GET");
```

Has someone actually managed to make this work without boiler-plate code?